# Debugging a C++ program in Intellij IDEA

Tags: c++, debugging, intellij-idea, ubuntu-12.04

I have been successfully run a C/C++ program in Intellij IDEA. But how to debug it? The operation system is Ubuntu 12.04 and Intellij IDEA version is 13.0.3. The path of the gdb is set to /usr/bin/gdb.
The settings in the Run/Debug configurations are also set to its own path.

The problem occurs when start Debugging, nothing happens in the IDE. How to fix it?

Comment: Have tried out the new C/C++ IDE based on IntelliJ: [CLion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/)?